# Can we use "After" as "Then"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I heard that it is okay to use the word "After" in the meaning of the word "Then". Is it true? For example: "After I will play tennis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true.

A good reason for this is based on sequence of events. Let's say you have a routine of going swimming and then eating food. The following is perfectly reasonable: *I go swimming. Then, I eat food*. *Then* in the second sentence says one thing follows another; the second sentence follows the first.

*After* has the exact same meaning in this context. The following is also perfectly reasonable: *I go swimming. After, I eat food*. *After*, like *then*, says one thing follows another, also emphasizing that the second thing is immediately adjacent to the first thing.

Note that it is very beneficial to put a comma after these two words, otherwise the examples I provided could potentially mean the exact opposite (I go swimming after I eat food).